# In Oracle, how do I remove the "plus" sign from date subtractions?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following code:

```
NUMTODSINTERVAL((hur.end_date -hur.creation_date), 'day') 
                               AS "Average Security Appr Duration"
```

The issue is that it returns something like:

```
+1115 11:47:23.0000000
```

How can I format it more user-friendly, in particular remove the `+` sign?

```
"1,115 DAYS, 11 HOURS 47 minutes"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`EXTRACT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) and [`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(DAY    FROM t_interval), 'fm99999') || ' DAYS '    ||
       TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM t_interval), 'fm99')    || ' HOURS '   ||
       TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM t_interval), 'fm99')    || ' MINUTES ' ||
       TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM t_interval), 'fm99.0')  || ' SECONDS' 
                                                 AS "Average Security Appr Duration" 
  FROM (SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL((hur.end_date -hur.creation_date), 'day') AS t_interval 
          FROM dual);
```

This produces an output like `1 DAYS 18 HOURS 18 MINUTES 3.0 SECONDS`.

Answer (score 1):

Use extract function to work with intervals, e.g

```
extract(day from myinterval)
```

will return you amount of days.